# How do i know if the success or failure block was executed in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am working with `AFNetworking`. I created a class called `MyRequest` which extends `NSObject`. I created a method called `requestForPost` that

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": variable1};
[manager POST:@"http://app.com/resources" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

When i am going to call a `webservice`, i pass the parameter dictionary to the above method so it'll execute the `webservice`.

How, am i suppose to know if the `webservice` request was a success or a failure. How am i supposed to pass the result back to the `ViewController` that i called the above `webservice`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same way as AFNetworking do: use blocks. One for the success, one for the failure. Using this way in your `UIViewController`, you will know if your request was a success or failure, and the object returned.

In your API file:

```
- (void)yourAPIMethodWithSuccess:(void (^)(id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": variable1};
    [manager POST:@"http://app.com/resources" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        success(responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        failure(error);
    }];
}
```

In your controller:

```
- (void)fetchDataForRequest{
    YourAPIInstance yourAPIMethodWithSuccess:^(id expectedObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", expectedObject);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I want to have the post request method in another class and call it from what ever viewCOnroller i want. This way i can assure my code is clean. But, how am i to know if the success or failure block was executed ?

Comment: Your going have to return a block like above, if you want just return a `BOOL success`.

Comment: I added an example for your controller. If your request failed, you will be in the failure block, if success in success block. After, you can add more check following the object you get in the success block... You can customise the return of your block as you like as said @BooRanger

Comment: For example, your request will take 5 seconds. the code in the viewcontroller will not pause for 5 seconds till the request is completed but, it'll continue to execute the remaining code in the viewController. I think i have to use protocols to make this work. Please advice

Comment: It's not a problem. A block don't block your execution, but will be called only when your request is done. If you have some codes which need the callback to be executed, you just have to put it in the block. A protocol will work too, it's only depending of what you prefer between both. Personally, I will recommend you block for this case.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to implement the above using protocols ?

Comment: Check on stack overflow, you will have a lot of example for this kind example.

Comment: @Illep above answer shows you the best way of doing this. It's much cleaner to use blocks approach like above rather than protocol approach.

Comment: How can i pass a dictionary as a parameter to the `yourAPIMethodWithSuccess ` method ?

Comment: Just change the block parameter. "id" -> "NSDictionary"

Comment: for  `expectedObject` or `responseObject ` ?

Comment: `responseObject` is the block from `AFNetworking`, you can't change it. But you have no limit about your block: more parameters, type, named... it's all up to you.

Comment: Can you please show me an example. I am a bit lost trying to add an additional parameter ?

Comment: `- (void)yourAPIMethodWithSuccess:(void (^)(id responseObject, NSDictionary *secondsParams))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure`, or `- (void)yourAPIMethodWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *aParam))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure`. Also, you should read apple reference about blocks if you don't know how it's working

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom network layer class to interact with server, where you can make custom handling of any request results/errors. And then use this class in your view controllers.

In this case you can change code in one place and can be sure that everything will be changed for all app, where you use this network layer class